# how to use argument as table name in a postgresql SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I've got a function to return relevant position of an array matching given value like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_index(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS TABLE (i_position int)
  AS $$

    SELECT 
           i+i_step AS i_position
    FROM   (VALUES(1),(2)) steps(i_step),
                          generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i
    WHERE $2[i] = $1 

$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Instead of passing a single value to the function, I want to pass a table name, as one column of the table would be used to do the value comparison (WHERE $2[i] = $1 ), instead of a single value passed to the function. However, it doesn't seem like the function support SQL using argument as table name.

I'm wondering if there's alternative. I'd like to use SQL function instead of PLPGSQL, for the sake of performance. As our table is huge.

I'd like to achieve something like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_index(tbl ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS TABLE (i_position int)
  AS $$

    SELECT 
           i+i_step AS i_position
    FROM   (VALUES(1),(2)) steps(i_step),
                          generate_series(array_lower($2,1), array_upper($2,1)) AS i,
                          $1
    WHERE $2[i] = $1.col1 

$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in SQL function - It doesn't support **dynamic sql**. You have to use PLpgSQL - `EXECUTE` statement.

SQL function is faster than PLpgSQL only when *inlining* is successful. When it isn't successful, and SQL function should be evaluated, then PLpgSQL should not be slower. When body of SQL function contains SRF functions like `generate_series`, then inlining is not effective.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I'm going to use array instead of table to pass in the list of values. By reading this https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/ I'm wondering how i can changeWHERE $2[i]  =ANY($1) to something like  WHERE $2[i]  =ANY(values($1))

Comment: When you use clause `VALUES`, then you have to use subselect filter. But it has different meaning than what you want probably.